# GSON, unable to deserialise Json String

Tags: json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization, android

I'm writing a mobile apple using Java.

In the first step I need to read in a line of Json string and convert it to a object which looks like

```
Map<String,Object>.
```

I'm using Google Gson but since I am so new to coding I have difficulty writing the deserialising code. I've tried 2 hour for this but still failed.

Can someone help ? Really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]. 'Shortened code' that isn't real code is not 'easy reference' it's something nobody can easily help you with. Write an [mcve] that others can run, show what the data you are trying to read looks like, what exact errors you get and when, describe the difference between what happens and what you expect to happen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so assuming you already correctly converted your JSON to String, here's how you should go about this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type yourObjectType =  
    new TypeToken<Map<String, YourObject>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, YourObject> yourMap = gson.fromJson(yourJSONString, yourObjectType);
```

There's a great [tutorial series](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization) on GSON by FutureStudio, I think it's worthy to go through each of the tutorials, and [this one](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-maps) particularly for your case.